# Alias an existing Slack command

Tags: alias, slack, slack-api

I see plenty of documentation for making a custom Slack command, but I'm trying to alias an existing one.

IE, we have the command `/bluejeans` to start a Bluejeans meeting, but because of an inside joke I'd love to alias that to also kick off through `/bleujean`.

I can't find a place for this in the GUI, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not configure alias commands in Slack, but there are other ways to get an alias.

`/bluejeans` obviously is a non-standard slash command. Either added through customization or by installing a Slack app that provides that new command.

You have two options to add the alias:

1. The owner of the current slash commands add its as an alias (that basically means adding another slash command and linking it to the same server script for processing). That also works for custom slash commands and Slack apps.
2. You add `/bleujean` as your own new slash command and link it to your own server script that then invokes the `/bluejeans` via the undocumented Web API method [chat.command](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md).

Comment: Unfortunately the chat.command api requires a deprecated scope (`post`), which you can no longer configure an app to use.